# Heroku: Unable to deploy, cannot parse procfile

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment

This is what my root directory for the app looks like looks like:

```
flask-submission-form
 ├ app
 │ ├ templates
 │ │ ├ base.html
 │ │ └ index.html
 │ ├ app.py
 │ ├ extensions.py
 │ └ __init__.py
 ├ assets
 │ └ css
 │ │ ├ custom.css
 │ │ └ main.css
 ├ .env
 ├ .gitignore
 ├ definitions.py
 ├ gulpfile.js
 ├ package-lock.json
 ├ package.json
 ├ postcss.config.js
 ├ Procfile
 ├ README.md
 ├ requirements.txt
 └ tailwind.config.js
```

This is what the `app/` directory looks like:

```
app
 ├ templates
 │ ├ base.html
 │ └ index.html
 ├ app.py
 ├ extensions.py
 └ __init__.py
```

My `__init__.py` contains my main app code, which is like so:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os
from .extensions import register_extensions

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    register_extensions(app)

    @app.route("/", methods =["GET", "POST"])
    def index():
        if request.method == "POST":
           #  Do a Bunch of Stuff
```

And my `app.py` looks like this:

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
```

I put this in my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app.app:create_app()
```

But when I try to deploy this to Heroku, I'm getting the following error:

```
remote:  !     Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.
remote:  !     If the problem persists, see https://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID 28547bd1-bce5-f7f2-e770-b2cb7b73be26.
remote:
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: fbbc38150c6a8d344932d53a7c40ae4880c288c8
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version fbbc38150c6a8d344932d53a7c40ae4880c288c8
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
```

How do I configure my `Procfile` correctly, given my application structure, so that it can be correctly deployed? If it helps, [this is my repo](https://github.com/thedivtagguy/submission).

Comment: hey what is the decoding , do it utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is deployed perfectly from the repo you have shared. If it's persisting the same problem then probably it's the problem with the encoding of your file.
See this question for reference - https://help.heroku.com/CH22EKEK/why-am-i-seeing-push-failed-can-not-parse-procfile-when-deploying-my-app

#### Logs

```sh
PS C:\Users\lovekesh\Desktop\npx\submission> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 137, done.
Counting objects: 100% (137/137), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Writing objects: 100% (137/137), 46.62 KiB | 9.32 MiB/s, done.
Total 137 (delta 61), reused 137 (delta 61), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:                         Detected buildpacks: Python,Node.js
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.10
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.8
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting certifi==2021.5.30
remote:          Downloading certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet==4.0.0
remote:          Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
remote:        Collecting click==8.0.1
remote:          Downloading click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Collecting colorama==0.4.4
remote:          Downloading colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting contentful==1.13.0
remote:          Downloading contentful-1.13.0.tar.gz (24 kB)
remote:        Collecting contentful-management==2.11.0
remote:          Downloading contentful_management-2.11.0.tar.gz (38 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==2.0.1
remote:          Downloading Flask-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-Assets==2.0
remote:          Downloading Flask_Assets-2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
remote:        Collecting hashids==1.3.1
remote:          Downloading hashids-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==2.10
remote:          Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==2.0.1
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==3.0.1
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dotenv==0.17.1
remote:          Downloading python_dotenv-0.17.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.25.1
remote:          Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
remote:        Collecting six==1.16.0
remote:          Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3==1.26.5
remote:          Downloading urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
remote:        Collecting webassets==2.0
remote:          Downloading webassets-2.0-py3-none-any.whl (142 kB)
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==2.0.1
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: contentful, contentful-management
remote:          Building wheel for contentful (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for contentful (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for contentful: filename=contentful-1.13.0-py3-none-any.whl size=23484 sha256=4e9ed2216013ef878985095ecdef4bd5b093ad3cbd269d5630a88016b7f13544
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-dvbrmrc3/wheels/65/58/bf/7fd9898c0cf50c98ce0ec77ba81cf6b06c54fc5ef13cbdf260
remote:          Building wheel for contentful-management (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for contentful-management (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for contentful-management: filename=contentful_management-2.11.0-py3-none-any.whl size=71724 sha256=c8fa877ec3fb64a11dbbf6dbb10d015fcdc8efbb6ea1c02f1df6a717f88c5533
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-dvbrmrc3/wheels/00/cc/2b/c8d92b042eafa41d358a214cd49cb4b8ed01250b000488cb23
remote:        Successfully built contentful contentful-management
remote:        Installing collected packages: certifi, chardet, click, colorama, urllib3, idna, requests, six, python-dateutil, contentful, contentful-management, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, Flask, webassets, Flask-Assets, gunicorn, hashids, python-dotenv
remote:        Successfully installed Flask-2.0.1 Flask-Assets-2.0 Jinja2-3.0.1 MarkupSafe-2.0.1 Werkzeug-2.0.1 certifi-2021.5.30 chardet-4.0.0 click-8.0.1 colorama-0.4.4 contentful-1.13.0 contentful-management-2.11.0 gunicorn-20.0.4 hashids-1.3.1 idna-2.10 itsdangerous-2.0.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-dotenv-0.17.1 requests-2.25.1 six-1.16.0 urllib3-1.26.5 webassets-2.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 52.8M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://stackcwww.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/stackcwww.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I had fixed it earlier in the day when I realized it might be an issue with the encoding. Your answer is valuable for future users, thank you for taking the time to verify and solve the issue :D